# MSSQL Connection login failed for user in node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

i am trying to connect mssql database but i couldnt achieve that.

When i connect mssql on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xdI0.png 
-- Because of Windows Authentication, i have no password. And there is a username field passive as default, also node js doesnt accept default user name. Why? and what i am doing wrong? 
 When i try to execute js file; [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty0zA.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSgTG.png) -- gives an user name error in cmd 
**db.js file;**

```
var sql = require('mssql');
// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'DESKTOP-S9H932R\\CUNEYT',
    password: '',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'cuneyt' 
};

// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from borsa', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
});
```

**package.json file;**

```
{
  "name": "mssql_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "db.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mssql": "^6.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: i solved my issue, i created an user in mssql server and gave it read and write permission.

Answer (score 1):

OP solved but for anyone having trouble my issue was that I was connecting to a local DB within a domain. I had to add the option to my config object to be like

```
config:{
user:'xxxx',
password:'xxxx',
server:'servername',
database:'yourdb'
domain:'yourdomainname'}
```